# jQuery: Find the element with a particular custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to find the element with a particular value for a custom attribute.

E.g. I want to find a the `div` which has the attribute `data-divNumber="6"`.

```
var number = 6;
var myDiv = $('[data-divNumber = number]');
```

I tried using http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ but what I've done doesn't work.

There is precisely one element with that particular value for the attribute.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
var number = 6;
var myDiv = $('div[data-divNumber="' + number + '"]');
```

Comment: So does putting the div in here $('div[... specify only to look at div elements?

Answer (score 8):

You need to do some string addition to get the number into your selector and the value needs to be quoted.

```
var number = 6;
var myDiv = $('[data-divNumber="' + number + '"]');
```

What you're trying to produce after the string addition is this result:

```
$('[data-divNumber="6"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is:

```
var number = 6;
var myDiv = $('[data-divNumber="'+number+'"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can use string interpolation:

```
let number = 6;
let myDiv = $(`div[data-divNumber="${number}"]`);
```