# Remove / Delete a dynamically created partial view mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a remove/delete a dynamically created partial view. 
This is my ADD script.

```
    $("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/Employees/Add'
    }).success(function (partialView) {
        $('#AddSchedule').append("<tbody>" + partialView + "</tbody>");      
    });
});
```

this is the add controller

```
public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var schedViewModel = new FacultySchedViewModel();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Employees/_DynamicView.cshtml", schedViewModel);
    }
```

this is the partial view  _DynamicView.cshtml

```
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("New")){
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteThis", "MyController", null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.Schedule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </td> }
```

what i can't figure out are

1. how to get the ID generated by BeginItemCollection
2. use the ID in a remove script
3. action on the controller

**EDIT**
1. How to connect it to a button or a link for removing the row

**Added the view on the the Main of the partial view**

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.New.Count(); i++)
                {               
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.New[i])

                }
```

Comment: What do your mean _"the ID generated by BeginItemCollection"_. The `BeginItemCollection` add a `Guid` as an indexer to the controls `name` and `id` attributes. It has no relevance at all to identifying an item to delete. Show you `remove` function (but why do you also have an action link to a delete method?)

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the html appended to `#AddSchedule` previously added by a corresponding add, in javascript?

Comment: And what is the property in `FacultySchedViewModel` that uniquely identifies it (which is what you need to delete the item)

Comment: @StephenMuecke. I added an edit in my question. And for your second question - its ID but i didn't include it my view model.. so I will include it..

Comment: @StuartLC.. yes, exactly.. on some post that I've read it the remove script has some `('#AddSchedule').empty();` but it seems like it will remove all apended partial view.. I'm not sure though..

Comment: what is "AddSchedule"? is it table or div? and for remove, are you want at client side or at server side operation you want.

Comment: @arjay the `AddSchedule` is a table.. and I need a client side removal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeginItemCollection add a Guid as an indexer to the controls name and id attributes. It has no relevance at all to identifying an item to delete. You need add include the value of the property that identifies the `FacultySchedViewModel` object. Assuming its `int ID`, then change the partial to include a button and add the ID as a `data-` attribute

```
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("New"))
{
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@Model.ID">Delete</button></td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.Schedule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Then your script would be

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Delete")'; // assumes its in the same controller
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  if (id) { // or if(id == 0) depending if your property is nullable
    row.remove(); // the item never existed so no need to call the server
    return;
  }
  $.post(url, { ID: id }, function(response) {
    if(response) {
      row.remove(); // OK, so remove the row
    } else {
      // Oops - display and error message?
    }
  });
});
```

and the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
{
  // Delete the item in the database
  return Json(true); // or if there is an error, return Json(null); to indicate failure
}
```

Side note:

1. `$('#AddSchedule').append("<tbody>" + partialView + "</tbody>");` is
   adding a new `tbody` element for each item. Instead the main view
   should include the `tbody` element and give it the `id` so its
   `$('#AddSchedule').append(partialView);` or use `$('#AddSchedule
   tbody')append(partialView);`
2. Does the model your posting back really have a property named `New`
   (as you indicate in the `BeginItemCollection` method)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't save it in the database.. how will I remove it in the controller?

Comment: See my updates. If the model has not yet been saved, you just check the ID (i.e. `null` if its `int? ID` or `0` if its `int`) and if so just remove the row from the table - no need to call controller

Comment: I added the <tbody> on the append for the style... And the property of `BeginItemCollection` method is  really `New`..

Comment: Why have a property named `New`? This means if you want to edit existing items you need to create a separate partial with identical code (just changing the generated prefix). Surely the fact the ID is either `null` or `0` identifies it as a new vs existing `FacultySchedViewModel`

Comment: You should not be adding a `<tbody>` element for each row. Just style the `<tr>` element (note I added that in my code in the partial - the valid child of a `<tbody>` element is a `<tr>` element, not `<td>` elements)

Comment: the New is a list in the model that is used in the loop on the main view... I added the code of the loop

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense. You have a `$("#btnAdd")` function that adds a new record. How can `Model.New` have any items (they don't exist yet!) What about existing items that do exist - would you have a property named `Existing`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your html render, what I suggest to modify your partial view as

```
From 
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteThis", "MyController", null)
To
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteThis", "MyController", new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" } )  //add custom properties for here, which you can grab at client side or give css here.
```

Now search the anchor link via [jQuery: Find the element with a particular custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628413/jquery-find-the-element-with-a-particular-custom-attribute)
When you get id, you can go parent like `$('#id').parent().parent().hide() or empty()`

or

As second option, is on click of `Delete button` call the same controller , but with a parameter to identify delete, so while returning give the null will bind in ajax again with empty string.

[Why does Html.ActionLink render "?Length=4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824279/why-does-html-actionlink-render-length-4)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1787278.aspx?Add+and+remove+partial+views